# Nokogiri write_html_to oddness?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I want to use Nokogiri to parse an HTML fragment, do something to it, and write out valid HTML to a file.

That seems easy, but I'm confused why Nokogiri's `doc.write_html_to` method is wrapping my fragment in an empty element tag brackets.

```
# Try this in IRB
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<h1 id="foo">Hello</h1>')

# Option #1 - Wrapped in Empty Tag
doc.write_html_to(File.new('write_html_to.html', 'w'), :encoding => 'UTF-8')
# => <><h1 id="foo">Hello</h1></>

# Option #2 - Works as needed
File.open('doc_to_html.html', 'w'){|f| f.write(doc.to_html(:encoding => 'UTF-8'))}
# => <h1 id="foo">Hello</h1>
```

Any ideas why option #1 is wrapping the HTML fragment file in an empty tag?

Comment: Did you report it as a bug ? Otherwise I can do the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the implementation of `Node#write_html_to` when writing a `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment`. I found that `write_xhtml_to` works correctly:

```
doc.write_xhtml_to(File.new('write_xhtml_to.html', 'w'), :encoding => 'UTF-8')

# => <h1 id="foo">Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll add an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used `File.write` for a single-line write. It'd be just as convenient as using Nokogiri's `write_html_to`, and shorter than using `File.open` with a block:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<h1 id="foo">Hello</h1>')
File.write('write_html_to.html', doc.to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the Ruby terseness tip, but not really an answer to the Nokogiri issue.

Comment: It's a bug. Report it, when work around it. I'd work around it using the shorter method.